# Watching subvalues of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a dynamic `array` with items, which could look like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Ford', checked: false},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', checked: true},
    {id: 3, name: 'BMW', checked: false}
];
```

I want to react whenever a `checked` value is changed, and know which item it was changed on.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register an `ng-change` event to the check boxes bound. If you indeed really want to add a watch you can use the deep watch option. `$scope.$watch('items', fn, true)`. However i will not to use a watcher unless it is ***absolutely required***.

Example:-

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="carSelected(item)" />{{item.name}}</label>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ford',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mercedes',
    checked: true
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'BMW',
    checked: false
  }];

  $scope.carSelected = function(item) {
    //Do something with the selected
    console.log(item);
  }
  
  $scope.$watch('items', function(){
    console.log("Item updated");
  }, true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="carSelected(item)" />{{item.name}}</label>
  <p>
    {{items}}
</div>
```

Comment: Of course. I don't know what I was thinking - thank you