# Using $watch to handle changes in checkboxes array. Doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have three checkboxes

```
<span class="checkbox-label clicks-label"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[0]">Clicks <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </span>
            <span class="checkbox-label views-label"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[1]">Views <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </span>
            <span class="checkbox-label ctr-label"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[2]">Click-Trough Rate <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </span>
```

And this code in the controller

```
$scope.checkboxes = [true,true,true];


$scope.$watch('checkboxes', function(newValue, oldValue){
            debugger
        });
```

I want to run some scenario when one of this checkboxes changes value.

but when i change the value i don't reach the debugger. Any ideas?
What is the right way to do it? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watching subvalues of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000795/watching-subvalues-of-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using the array like how you have you would need to either use a `deep watch` (`$scope.$watch('expn', fn, true)`) or [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) (specially designed to watch collections but not deep watched). Also note that you can bind an `ng-change` event to those check boxes and avoid adding any watchers (An answer on those lines [you can find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000795/watching-subvalues-of-array/28000825#28000825)).

Try:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('checkboxes', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
});
```

On a different note, Instead of repeating the checkboxes in the view you could create a better view model with array of objects even including the checkbox names etc and bind it with an `ng-change` event.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkboxes = [true, true, true];


  $scope.$watchCollection('checkboxes', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span class="checkbox-label clicks-label"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[0]">Clicks <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </span>
  <span class="checkbox-label views-label"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[1]">Views <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </span>
  <span class="checkbox-label ctr-label"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[2]">Click-Trough Rate <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </span>
</div>
```